# Why is the wild card character * so different between the zip and rm commands?

Tags: shell, wildcards, rm, zip

I put together a script to do some file operations for me. I am using the wild card operator `*` to apply functions to all files of a type, but there is one thing I don't get. I can `unzip` all files in a folder like this

```
unzip "*".zip
```

However, to remove all zip files afterward, I need to do

```
rm *.zip
```

That is, it does not want the quotation marks. The unzip, on the other hand, does not work if I just give it the * (gives me a warning that "files were not matched").

Why is this different? To me, this seems like the exact same operation. Or am I using the wild card incorrectly?

[Introductions to the wild card](http://www.linfo.org/wildcard.html) in Unix do not really go into this, and I could not locate anything in the `rm` or `zip` docs.

I am using the terminal on a Mac (Yosemite).

Comment: I had no idea `unzip` could do this without the normal `for f in *.zip;do...done` shell loop.  Such a weird non-unix-like command line UI.

Comment: @Peter I think you misunderstand the situation. `unzip` applies the glob to the contents of an archive; you cannot get them from bash with a wildcard. (You'd need ```for f in `unzip -l archive.zip`; do ... done`)

Comment: @alexis: I knew about `unzip` accepting globs to match inside a single zip file.  But this is different; I actually tried `unzip '*.zip'` in a directory with multiple zip files, and it extracts all files from all zips.  Like I said, super-weird.  `tar` doesn't have any mode of operation like that.

Comment: @Peter I see... yeah that's weird, especially since unzip _will not accept multiple commandline arguments!_ Clearly a Windows-only implementation. I misinterpreted the OP's description of the task.

Comment: @alexis: [PKZip pre-dates Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP).  It's a DOS command-line program, first released in 1989.  The Unix port uses basically the same cmdline-parsing code, AFAIK.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You've explained the situation very well. The final piece to the puzzle is that `unzip` can handle wildcards itself:

http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html

> ARGUMENTS
>
> file[.zip]
>
> ...
>
> Wildcard expressions are similar to those supported in commonly used Unix shells (sh, ksh, csh) and may contain:
>
> * matches a sequence of 0 or more characters

By quoting the * wildcard, you prevented your shell from expanding it, so that `unzip` sees the wildcard and deals with expanding it according to its own logic.

`rm`, by contrast, does not support wildcards *on its own*, so attempting to quote a wildcard will instruct `rm` to look for a literal asterisk in the filename instead.

The reason that `unzip *.zip` does not work is that `unzip`'s syntax simply does not allow for multiple zip files; if there are multiple parameters, it expects the 2nd and subsequent ones to be files in the archive:

> unzip [-Z] [-cflptTuvz[abjnoqsCDKLMUVWX$/:^]] file[.zip] [file(s) ...] [-x xfile(s) ...] [-d exdir]

Comment: thanks, that makes sense! if i understand correctly, in one case I am speaking `unzip`'s own language, in the other case the general unix lingo?

Comment: Correct. It's important to keep in mind what your shell does vs what a program does.

Comment: pkzip originated on DOS which did not expand wildcards passed to programs.

Comment: @patrick the unix way of processing multiple files with a program that can only work with one file at a time is to use a loop.  e.g. `for f in *.zip ; do unzip -v "$f" ; done`.   and a big part of the reason WHY the shell does the filename expansion etc itself is sot that each individual program doesn't have to (which would result in having lots of independently-written implementations of wildcard expansion that differed in small but annoying ways).

Answer (score 25):

The difference between those two commands is the quoted `*` character. If you call a command in a shell and use the `*` character for an argument, the shell itself will evaluate the argument. See this example:

```
$ ls
file1.zip  file2.zip  file3.zip  file4.txt
```

Now with a `*`:

```
$ ls *.zip
file1.zip  file2.zip  file3.zip
```

The shell evaluates the wildcard and builds a command as follows:

```
$ ls file1.zip  file2.zip  file3.zip
```

With a quoted wildcard, it is interpreted as a file named (literally) `*.zip`:

```
$ ls "*".zip
ls: cannot access *.zip: No such file or directory
```

---

The `unzip` utility cannot be called with multiple zipped files as arguments. But, the developer chose another way for this. From the manpage:

> file[.zip]
>
> [...] Wildcard expressions are similar to
>   those supported in commonly used Unix shells (sh, ksh, csh) [...]
>   (**Be sure to quote any character that might otherwise be interpreted or
>   modified by the operating system**, particularly under Unix and VMS.)

Comment: Do you know why the authors of `unzip` chose to go that route, rather than allow for multiple zipped files as arguments?

Comment: @DavidEtler I don't know too.

Comment: I can't say why either, @DavidEtler, but as-built, unzip's syntax accepts filenames after the zipfile that are assumed to be contents of that zipfile. It'd be ambiguous whether you meant for a second zip file to be an "unzip me" parameter or a "unpack this internal zip file from the preceding archive" one.

Comment: @DavidEtler don't know what the developers were thinking, but everything was *much* slower and smaller back then. You usually weren't dealing with more than one zip file at a time.  You had floppies which held 90 or 250kB and you were really happy to have a 10MB disk drive. Things were compressed because they had to be, not just for intersystem transport.

Comment: To really highlight this shell expansion example replace `ls` with `echo`

Answer (score 8):

The difference is in the first case the shell itself expands the glob:

```
% cd /                                                       
% echo *
Applications Library Network System Users Volumes bin cores ...
%
```

while in the second case the application itself Does Something™ with that literal character:

```
% cd /
% perl -E 'chdir "/tmp" or die; say for glob($ARGV[0])' "*"
com.apple.launchd.aj4FEhYqm5
...
```

If unquoted, the shell first expands out the glob, and the command will be run with whatever that shell glob expanded out to.

Answer (score 2):

A command will receive the arguments after they have been processed by the shell.

On first processing, an unquoted `*` will be expanded by the shell (to the list of files in the present directory (pwd) that match the pattern):

```
echo *.zip
```

Will list all `.zip` files. But `echo "*".zip"` will **not**.

On first processing, a quoted `"*"` will not be expanded, it will be given to the command unzip as a parameter (after quoting has been removed). The command unzip will receive a parameter of `*.zip`:

```
$ echo unzip "*".zip
unzip *.zip
```

It is the command unzip which expand the `*` to the list of files.

---

It is also interesting that this two commands will **not** perform the exact same final action, and who expands the `*` changes:

```
unzip "*".zip                ### the command unzip expands `*.zip`.
unzip *.zip                  ### the shell expands `*.zip`.
```

The first command receives a `*.zip` which it expands to process all files.
The second command `unzip` will receive a list of all `.zip` files in the pwd, which it will not process, as the unzip developer has chosen to reject the expansion of more than one `zip` file.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are needed because of the way zip handles multiple arguments:

`rm`: remove all files in the argument list

`zip`: unzip the file in the first argument. only extract the files in the remaining arguments.

```
$ ls *.zip
file1.zip  file2.zip  file3.zip
$ unzip *.zip
Archive:  file1.zip
caution: filename not matched:  file2.zip
caution: filename not matched:  file3.zip
```

as you can see, it tries to find file2.zip and file3.zip inside file1.zip

in order to allow you to extract multiple zip files at once, zip supports interpreting the glob by itself, with a different result.