# Selectively extract files from a .zip archive from command line

Tags: linux, grep, zip, compression

Suppose I have a large zip file (>50GB) and I want to extract some files off of it from the command line.

To get the files I run the command:

```
unzip -l myfile.zip | grep "foo"
```

which gives me a list of zip entries; how do I extract those files that pass through the grep filter? I tried using `xargs unzip -j` but I'd like some cleaner solution as the zip entries require cleaning of useless information.

Comment: You can just do `unzip -j myfile.zip '*foo*'`

Comment: Nice and clean.

Comment: be careful if you're grepping for anything that `unzip -l` *also* reports in the header or trailer; e.g. "archive", "zip", "length", "date", "time", "name", "file", or numbers that match the total bytes or number of files.

Answer (score 6):

[Stéphane has the right idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382404/selectively-extract-files-from-a-zip-archive-from-command-line#comment679630_382404) to pass `zip` the wildcard corresponding to the filenames that you'd like to extract. Parsing the output of `unzip` means you have to watch out for the header and trailer lines that come along.

Use something like:

```
unzip -j myfile.zip '*foo*'
```

being careful to [quote the wildcards from the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284638/117549).

If you continue along the direction of grepping `unzip`'s output, strip out the header and trailer and reduce it to the filename column:

```
unzip -l myfile.zip | sed '1,3d; /---------                     -------/d; $d'|cut -c31-
```